# Human Readable SQL Server CDC Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, audit

We have implemented SQL Server CDC as a background auditing tool across multiple databases.  We have a new requirement to implement a human readable audit report accessible from the user interface.  Currently our only solution is to develop a separate stored procedure per user process to return that human readable output for display on the UI but this is taking too long.
Is there a tool set or generic approach to producing human readable output from CDC data which we would use to short cut this development process?

Comment: Import/export (whatever's more appropriate) that data to a separate DB with some ETL process of your choice; you are then free to restructure/reindex it so queries on it operate with acceptable speed (and, as a bonus, you offload this from your main server(s), since those presumably have other important things to do). As to whether there are ready-made tools for this, possibly, but recommendations for those are off-topic for SO.

Comment: What's not human readable about the data in CDC tables?